# Notepad++ numbers not appearing correctly

Tags: notepad++

I recently installed Eclipse and then Notepad++ to write Java code somewhere other than BlueJ. In both the cases, the digits are not appearing correctly. For instance, 3 and 5 are appearing as =, 6 as D, 7 as 8, 8 as ~ and 0 as ~.

[image: https://gyazo.com/ffd8ad28d868de9e96c694c20159b784]

Comment: No, I have tried it.